# Why do i have my name space on every SyndicationItem element?

Tags: c#, rss, syndicationfeed, syndication-item

I'm trying to find out why my namespace(`xmlns:ren="http://www.example.com/rss2/ext"`) appears on every custom syndicationItem element (`<ren:rssTranslationType typeId="1" xmlns:ren="http://www.example.com/rss2/ext">Original Content</ren:rssTranslationType>`) when it's already declared at the top of the file?
Bizarrely this only happens after the .rss file has been read into the syndicationFeed > contents updated > then spat back out. Creating a new rss file works fine (no additional name space usages).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to cure it: 
  `XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings{Indent = true,                          NamespaceHandling = NamespaceHandling.OmitDuplicates};`

```
 using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(sourcePath, settings))
            {
                rssFeedData.SaveAsRss20(xmlWriter);
            }
```